# Is perforce/vault interoperable

Tags: perforce, sourcegear-vault

I am wondering if we can use P4 client to access Vault server? Are those two interoperable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need a P4 client to access a P4 server, and a Vault client to access a Vault server.

Answer (score 0):

You can, however, use both environments at the same time individually to keep both repositories synched up. Set the Working directory from the vault (inherit sub-directories) to the same/main directory layout used in Perforce.